# ntp daemon seems useless and why my server date time is far behind my local time

Tags: ubuntu, ntp, clock-synchronization

I've installed ntp daemon in ubuntu to sync my date time with the network time. Now my time on the server is 11:00 while my PC date/time is 19:30.

Now all my transactions date/times are logged incorrectly. How should I adjust that? Should I use the normal date command in Linux terminal?

Comment: Check your server's time zone.

Comment: -1?! Could you possibly tell the reason for your down vote?

Comment: The output from `ntpq -nc peers` on each of the hosts would be useful.

Comment: Please hover over the "downvote" button, it will tell you the reason why a question *should* be downvoted.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, setting timezone solved my problem. thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If your time is super far off Ntp will not adjust it.  Stop the ntp service. Run ntpdate your.time.server and then restart the ntp service  it should keep accurate time then assuming it has good access to enough time sources.